# Is using FileSystemWatchers sharing the same event handler safe?

Tags: .net, thread-safety, filesystemwatcher

Is using FileSystemWatchers sharing the same event handler safe?

Is it safe having multiple FileSystemWatchers watching different directories using the same event handler?

```vb
Class Snippets
    Private _watchPaths As New List(Of String) From {"x:\Dir1", "x:\Dir2"}
    Private _watchers As List(Of FileSystemWatcher)
    Private _newFiles As New BlockingCollection(Of String)

    Sub Watch()
        Dim _watchPaths As New List(Of String) From {"x:\Dir1", "x:\Dir2"}
        Dim watchers As List(Of FileSystemWatcher)

        For Each path In _watchPaths
            Dim watcher As New FileSystemWatcher
            AddHandler watcher.Created, Sub(s, e)
            _trace.DebugFormat("New file {0}", e.FullPath)
            'Do a little more stuff
            _newFiles.Add(e.FullPath)
            End Sub
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Or must we wrap the FileSystemWatcher in a Class like the following to make the event handlers thread-safe?

```vb
Class FileWatcher
    Private _fileSystemWatcher As New FileSystemWatcher

    Public Sub Start(path As String, filter As String, action As Action(Of Object, FileSystemEventArgs))
        With _fileSystemWatcher
            .Path = path
            .Filter = filter
            .EnableRaisingEvents = True
            AddHandler .Created, Sub(s, e)
            action(s, e)
            End Sub
        End With
    End Sub

    Public Sub [Stop]()
        _fileSystemWatcher.Dispose()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Here the usage of the helper Class:

```vb
Sub Watch
    For Each path In _watchPaths
        Dim Watcher as new FileWatcher
        watcher.Start(path, "*.txt"), Sub(s, e)
        _trace.DebugFormat("New file {0}", e.FullPath)
        'Do a little more stuff
        _newFiles.Add(e.FullPath)
        End Sub)      
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Events raised by the `FileSystemWatcher` are, by default, raised on thread pool threads.  Which means any data used within the event handler is "shared"--regardless of whether you have multiple handlers.  You should guard (e.g. `lock` access) this shared data to avoid corruption.

Alternatively, you can use [FileSystemWatcher.SynchronizingObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.synchronizingobject.aspx) to provide a synchronization context so that all events raised on a `FileSystemWatcher` occur on a single, or a known thread.  This is typically done if your event handlers touch GUI elements.

Comment: I extended code sample to show the usage of the helper Class FileWatcher. Are the event handlers thread-safe this way?

Comment: If the only "shared" data is a `BlockingCollection` object, you're thread-safe.  If you add anything else, you'll have to use something like SyncLock.

Comment: OK, so my first example using shared FileSystemWatcher events is not thread-safe. But wrapping the FileSystemWatcher in a class as I do with the FileWatcher sample should be thread-safe without any locking because each Created() event handler runs in its own FileSWatcher instance. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: I assume wrapping the FSW in a class as described above makes the event handlers thread safe.

Comment: @PeterMeini You write the event handlers, so no, this doesn't make them "thread safe".  This only means they are invoked on whatever synchronization context you provide for `SynchronizingObject`.  This this is a WinForms control, this means that all invocations of your event handler are done on the single UI thread.  But, that doesn't make your event handler magically thread-safe.

Comment: Peter Ritchie, thanks for getting back to this. I thought I prevented the FSW event handlers from being called by different threads concurrently by creating each FSW in a separate instance of the helper class FileWatcher. Is this assumption really wrong? BTW there is no UI thread, I am using the FSWs in a Windows Service.